# Close javascript popup by clicking anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am super novice and need a quick advice.
I need the close popup clicking by outside of modal.

Here is the codes. any tips about this?

```
    $('.login-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.signin-parent').show();
});
$('.signin-btn').on('click', function () {
    console.log('erhan')
    $('.signin-parent').show();
    $('.signup-parent').hide();
});
$('.signup-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.signin-parent').hide();
    $('.signup-parent').show();
});
$('.exit').on('click', function () {
    $('.signin-parent').hide();
    $('.signup-parent').hide();
})
```

It works finely but I click outside of popup it not close, anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: It should work if you listen for a click on `$(document)`, then in the event handler use `$.contains` to check if the event target is inside the popup. If it's not, then close it.

Comment: when i click exit icon it closed popup its okay but i want if i click the outside of the popup it will be closed too as i say im super novice and i cant wrote a code please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign an onclick event to the document or the body, then you can hide the pop-ups inside the event callback.

```
$(".login-popup").on("click",function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest(".signin").length != 0)
    return;
    $(".login-popup").hide();
})
```

Comment: Hocam alttaki yorumunuzdan sitenin adresini gördüm cevabı editledim yukarda verdiğim kod  bende çalışıyor. Sizde deneyebilirmisiniz.

Comment: Sizden allah razı olsun kafayı yemek üzereydim sayenizde bir adım ilerledim bir sorun haricinde harika çalışmakta eğer müsaitseniz sorunum şu popup içinde bir yere tıklayınca da popup'u kapatıyor

Comment: az önceki cevabı yeni yazdığım kodla değiştirebilirmisiniz birde böyle deneyin.

Comment: denedim hocam aynı sonucu aldım

Comment: Bir alternatif daha hocam bunuda deneyin isterseniz.

Comment: hocam oldu siz ne güzel insansınız 1.5 gündür yanıt arıyordum hiçbir şekilde bulamamıştım siz kendi sorununuz gibi ilgilenip çözdünüz benim size yardımcı olabileceğim herhangi bir konu var mı acaba memnuniyet duyarım

Comment: Ne demek, bende kendi soruma cevap bekliyordum beklerken yardımcı olayım dedim.

Comment: Keşke bilgim olsa da cevaplasam hocam tekrardan teşekkür ediyorum her şey için hayırlı geceler dilerim